# Create new marker on google maps through browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to give that functionality to my users. Use must be able to mark his location and get marked position's coordinates.  How shall i do that with google maps API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple click event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>

var map 
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    //map.setZoom(8);
    createMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function createMarker(position){
  //alert('test');
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: 'hello'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```